# Explain solution to $\int\frac{ 7\,dx}{x(x^4 + 2)}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Can someone please explain how they get from the step outlined in red to the one in blue? I tried using partial fractions to break it up but that didn't work, and I'm not sure how else I could rearrange it.

Comment: Partial fractions.

Comment: You likely just made a mistake when you were using partial fractions. Double check all your arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrals of this form can actually be solved with a simple factoring and then a slightly different substitution.

$$\int \frac{7}{x(x^4+2)} dx$$ = $$\int \frac{7}{x^5(1+\frac{2}{x^4})} dx$$ then letting $u=1+\frac{2}{x^4}$, $\frac{du}{-8}=\frac{dx}{x^5}$, so the integral becomes $$\frac{-7}{8}\int \frac{du}{u} $$=$\frac{-7}{8} \log (u)+C$=$\frac{-7}{8} \log (1+\frac{2}{x^4})+C$, which is equivalent to your answer after some manipulation.  We have the log is, $-\frac{7}{8}\log (1+\frac{2}{x^4})=-\frac{7}{8}\log (\frac{x^4+2}{x^4})=\frac{7}{8}\log (\frac{x^4}{x^4+2})$.

Answer (score 2):

Set a equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{u(u^2+2)}=\frac{A}{u}+\frac{Bu+C}{u^2+2},
\end{equation}
where $A,B$ and $C$ are constants. Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{u(u^2+2)}=\frac{(A+B)u^2+Cu+2A}{u(u^2+2)}
\end{equation}
and you can find $A,B$, and $C$ by checking coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{u(u^2+2)}&=\frac12\frac2{u(u^2+2)}
\\\\&=\frac12\frac{(u^2+2)-u^2}{u(u^2+2)}
\\\\&=\frac12\left(\frac{(u^2+2)}{u(u^2+2)}-\frac{u^2}{u(u^2+2)}\right)
\\\\&=\frac12\left(\frac1u-\frac{u}{u^2+2}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because: $\dfrac{1}{u(u^2+2)} = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{u}-\dfrac{u}{u^2+2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You can write it as $$\int \frac{\frac{7 dx}{x^5}}{1+\frac{2}{x^4}}$$

Put $$1+\frac{2}{x^4}=t$$